# SQLAlchemy: how exchange unique values in one transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

My versions:

```python
$ python
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> sqlalchemy.__version__
'1.0.0'
```

Let's look to the example for sqlite (in production I use mysql, but it does not matter here):

```python
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String

Base=declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'user'
   id      = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   name    = Column(String(16))
   tech_id = Column(Integer, unique=True, nullable=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = Session()
```

Now we add two records:

```python
u1=User(name="User1", tech_id=None)
u2=User(name="User2", tech_id=10)
s.add(u1)
s.add(u2)
s.commit()
```

Next try to modify them:

```python
u1=s.query(User).filter(User.name=="User1").first()
u2=s.query(User).filter(User.name=="User2").first()

u2.tech_id=None
u1.tech_id=10
s.commit()
```

After commit I've got the exception:

```python
<-- cut -->
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.tech_id [SQL: 'UPDATE user SET tech_id=? WHERE user.id = ?'] [parameters: ((10, 1), (None, 2))]
```

If I do like this:

```python
u2.tech_id=None
s.commit()
u1.tech_id=10
s.commit()
```

It's all right.

Is it possible to do requests by only one commit (by only one transaction)?

Comment: change that line to this "Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True)" and.

After this line s = Session() add "s.begin()" let me know if it helps?

Comment: I have understood that this is a constraint in MySQL (and I guess in SQLite). The behavior I need is "deferred constraint checking". MySQL by InnoDB does not support it yet.

Comment: I'm also trying to know, may someone will answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
#u1=s.query(User).filter(User.name=="User1").first()
#u2=s.query(User).filter(User.name=="User2").first()

#u2.tech_id=None
#u1.tech_id=10
#s.commit()

s.query(User).filter(User.name=="User2").update(
    {User.tech_id: None}
)
s.query(User).filter(User.name=="User1").update(
    {User.tech_id: 10}
)

s.commit()
```

The essence of that changes is to perform right sequence of actions. You can't create duplicate values for unique key (at least in mysql) even before committing. But you can create multiple NULL values for unique column.

Comment: As I wrote above in my comment it's not possible to do ONLY ONE transaction for this task due to InnoDB restrictions. So the solution you wrote is the same as: u2.tech_id=None; s.commit(); u1.tech_id=10; s.commit()

Comment: No. There is only one transaction In my example. Analog in SQL: start transaction; update 1; update 2; commit;

Comment: I've tried to check it one more time. It works. Thanks!